# App bar not showing in Android Studio Flamingo / API 34

Tags: android, kotlin

I'd like to have an App bar in my app, but I'm not getting the App bar to display by default when creating a new project. I'm following a tutorial with a slightly older version of Android Studio where this person's projects are just automatically getting it without changing any code or the manifest file. It there a way to display it without extra code and by default?